# Integrating multiple apps in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a project in Rails. It contains multiple sub-projects. They have a common login and the rest is separate for all. I want to integrate them all in the main project. The sub-projects are pretty big, so putting them all together will make it cumbersome to manage the code. Is there any way to integrate the sub-apps or gems in the main project?

Comment: You can consider migrate your sub-projects to [Rails engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider breaking your apps into engines. It's a great way to isolate functionality and make code modular. Here's a link to the Rails engine docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

If you need examples of real-world uses of engines you might consider looking at the code for Spree: https://github.com/spree/spree

With Spree you can add custom functionality by installing or building extensions, which are effectively Rails engines.

If you want to reference local gems/engines, you can point to them in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'mygem', :path => '/path/to/gem'
```

But make sure that the individual gems within your project don't have a .git folder, or you might run into errors regarding sub-modules.

Comment: thanks that's what i need. Also is there any way that i can make my sub projects as gems and then include them in my main project ?